# MS Access Database, Sequential Number in Select query

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have a query in MS Access SQL that is grabbing some information from my table. I'd like to include a field in my select statement that shows a integer and increments by X (1,2,3 or other) for each row.

So my data set would look something like:
(If incremented by 2)

```
Name   SKU     SortOrder <-This is my Auto Increment Field
Table  XYZ123  0
Chair  YRZ345  2
Sofa   UFD355  4
```

I'm not storing sort order in my table I just want to generate these values in Access SQL.

Thank you for your help.

---

**Update**
I've found the following article that explains a few ways to accomplish this through the access program and vba however i'm writting a c# program that's using an Access TSQL query to grab my data and then export into an excel file so i'm not going to be able to add anything to the original database in the Access Program, additionally going the temp table route, they mention it bloating the database.

https://accessexperts.com/blog/2015/07/28/ways-to-do-sequential-numbering-in-access/

I just want a column of sequential numbering that is created in my select statement, is that not possible?

Comment: Sequential order is possible but in MS Access SQL you need to order by some unique column(s). Would that be *Name* AND *SKU*?

Comment: Depending on what you plan to do with the data after you get it into your C# program you might also consider loading the results of your query into a DataTable and then adding the sequential values into the DataTable itself. As @Parfait suggests, there are ways to generate such values in an Access SQL query but they can be somewhat slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend do not use SQL to calculate such data. It's bad practice. 
It would better to add a field into table and perform calculations before sql statement execution if needed.

Anyway can implement function in VBA to do this. Like:

```
Private m_counter as Integer

Function CounterInit(Byval counter as Integer)
   m_counter = counter
End Function

Function CounterGetNext(Byval incr as Integer)
   m_counter = m_counter + incr

   CounterGetNext = m_counter
End Function
```

And then use CounterGetNext() in SQL. But you still have to call CounterInit() before sql execution. Use RecordsetType = Snapshot for such query.

Comment: I'm not sure how to pull in a VBA into my C# program. I cannot manipulate the DB directly it would have to be done on my side.

Comment: Why you need to do it in SQL? Do it in your app then in DataTable or where you are reading data from response.